# apache-poi: Handling cases when number of columns is more than 26

Tags: apache-poi

I have to create excel files with data coming from a database. So far number of columns is less than 26, so following works fine:

```
val c = ('A'.toInt + numCols- 1).toChar
val ref = s"A1:${c}1"
CellRangeAddress.valueOf(ref)
```

But for cases when number of columns is much higher, I need to map to a-z, or even double letters AA,AB,AC so on.

Is there some API in POI to make it easy

Comment: What's wrong with the Apache POI built-in function https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html#convertColStringToIndex-java.lang.String- ?

Comment: I need reverse of it..from number to alphabets.

Comment: That's also on the same util class! https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html#convertNumToColString-int-